Kaggle Notebook FailedPrecondition: 400 Use of API-based models is not allowed for Internet-disabled notebooks
I am working on kaggle notebook. When i run it says. I tried searching about this problem but no soultion found.

FailedPrecondition: 400 Use of API-based models is not allowed for
Internet-disabled notebooks

The code is actually throwing the problem is this:
genai.configure(api_key=mykey)
model = genai.GenerativeModel("gemini-1.5-flash")
response = model.generate_content("Explain how AI works")


This error message and approaches to resolve it are discussed at: https://www.kaggle.com/code/markishere/day-0-troubleshooting-and-faqs#No-internet-access

Possible causes

Make sure you are signed in to Kaggle
Make sure your phone number is verified in your Kaggle account at kaggle.com/settings.
Make sure the notebook has internet enabled

[instructions]


If !curl ipinfo.io still fails, you may need to refresh your browser tab and wait a few minutes.
Or, once you are verified and logged in, you can delete the notebook and fork it again from the original. This will create a new notebook with internet enabled.


